# Error in DiInstallDevice, InstallSelectedDriver - ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF

Tags: c++, c, winapi, setupapi

Okay, So I am getting this weird error stating "**ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF**" whenever I call DiInstallDevice, InstallSelectedDriver. The error code returned is
**3758096943**. When I look it up in err.exe, it says

```
# for decimal -536870353 / hex 0xe000022f :
  ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF                                  setupapi.h
# for hex 0xffffffff / decimal -1 :
  NO_TITLE                                                      ftsiface.h
  USE_DEFAULT                                                   ftsiface.h
  JET_wrnNyi                                                    esent98.h
# /* Function Not Yet Implemented */
  LZERROR_BADINHANDLE                                           lzexpand.h
# /* invalid input handle */
  MAPI_DIAG_NO_DIAGNOSTIC                                       mapidefs.h
  MSIDBERROR_FUNCTIONERROR                                      msiquery.h
# function error
  ERROR_UNHANDLED_ERROR                                         ntddchgr.h
# Unknown error condition
  PDR_ERROR                                                     penwin.h
# parameter or unspecified error
  ICERR_UNSUPPORTED                                             vfw.h
  ERROR_UNHANDLED_ERROR                                         winioctl.h
# Unknown error condition
# 11 matches found for "3758096943"
```

I am using setupapi, therefore the error, Internet searches reveal nothing whatsoever apart from the error being associated with the "**SetupCopyOEMInf()**" Which I have no relation to. The Driver in Question is an Intel HD 520 Signed Driver. I have verified it and downloaded it via Microsoft update catalog.

The driver is Selected using **SetupDiSetSelectedDriver()** and the correct device is selected using **SetupDiSetSelectedDevice()**. If anyone can point me in the right direction itwould be great!.

Code :

```
PopulateDeviceInstaceIds(L"PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_1916");
            SP_DRVINFO_DATA drvData;
            SP_DRVINFO_DETAIL_DATA drvDetailData;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA LocDevData;
            MakeDevClassHandles(handle,instancesOfDevice.at(0).c_str());
            SetDRVINFO(&LocDevData,&drvDetailData,&drvData,L"Intel Corporation",L"22.20.16.4836",TRUE);
            std::cout<<SetupDiSetSelectedDevice(handle,&LocDevData)<<endl;
            std::cout<<SetupDiSetSelectedDriver(handle,&LocDevData,&drvData)<<endl;
            if(&drvData!=NULL)
            {
                HMODULE libHandle = LoadLibraryW(L"newdev.dll");
                lpfnInstallSelectedDriver addr;
                DWORD rebootRec;
                addr = (lpfnInstallSelectedDriver)GetProcAddress(libHandle,"InstallSelectedDriver");
                if(addr!=NULL && addr(NULL,handle,NULL,TRUE,&rebootRec))
                {

                }
                else
                    cout<<"InstallSelectedDriver ERR : "<<GetLastError();
                 if(DiInstallDevice(NULL,handle,&LocDevData,&drvData,0,&nRebo))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"DiInstall Device error : "<<GetLastError();
                    std::cout<<"\n\nWaiting for upto 10 seconds for changes to reflect..";
                    Sleep(10000);
```

I guess this code will be enough, if not please let me know. The entire code is a few hundred lines, so.

The **SetDRVINFO()** function just sets the correct device and driver in the structures, i have verified them while debugging. Both the else cases throw the same error.

Comment: The error code `3758096943` does not match `ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF`. Please show the code you use to determine the error code.

Comment: @IInspectable Added code, and how do you tell the error code does not match, I used err.exe to find it.

Comment: Interesting, when I build the exe in x64, I do not get the error, Everything works as it should. But should it not throw ERROR_IN_WOW64 instead of ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF ????

Comment: @IInspectable actually it does: `ERROR_NO_CATALOG_FOR_OEM_INF` is defined as `(APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK|ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR|0x22F)`, `APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK` is `0x20000000`, and `ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR` is `0xC0000000`, which gives us `0x20000000|0xC0000000|0x22F` == `0xE000022F` == `3758096943`. (Yes, I know; I'm surprised it's not a standard Windows error code too.)

Comment: @andlabs: Actually, that's `-536870353`. `NTSTATUS` values are signed.